# Shibboleth Transcoding Rules not picking up data / passthrough attributes from azureAD integration

Tags: azure, shibboleth, idp

I followed the documentation to integrate Shibboleth 4.3 to use AzureAD as its proxy / IdP and everything redirects / responds as it should, but in the attribute resolver / claims rules, it is not picking up the attributes in the response back from Azure.  I can see in the logs it is going through the individual attributes / claims, which are mapped in the azureClaims.xml / resolver, but is not picking things to do the passthrough down to my servicer provider.

Below are the log entries in shibboleth:

```
2023-01-30 23:12:10,735 - 10.254.252.105 - INFO [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.saml2.profile.impl.ValidateSAMLAuthentication:511] - Profile Action ValidateSAMLAuthentication: No transcoding rule for Attribute (Name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid', NameFormat: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified')
2023-01-30 23:12:10,735 - 10.254.252.105 - INFO [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.saml2.profile.impl.ValidateSAMLAuthentication:511] - Profile Action ValidateSAMLAuthentication: No transcoding rule for Attribute (Name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier', NameFormat: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified')
2023-01-30 23:12:10,735 - 10.254.252.105 - INFO [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.saml2.profile.impl.ValidateSAMLAuthentication:511] - Profile Action ValidateSAMLAuthentication: No transcoding rule for Attribute (Name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname', NameFormat: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified')
2023-01-30 23:12:10,735 - 10.254.252.105 - INFO [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.saml2.profile.impl.ValidateSAMLAuthentication:511] - Profile Action ValidateSAMLAuthentication: No transcoding rule for Attribute (Name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider', NameFormat: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified')
2023-01-30 23:12:10,735 - 10.254.252.105 - INFO [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.saml2.profile.impl.ValidateSAMLAuthentication:511] - Profile Action ValidateSAMLAuthentication: No transcoding rule for Attribute (Name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences', NameFormat: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified')
2023-01-30 23:12:10,735 - 10.254.252.105 - INFO [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.saml2.profile.impl.ValidateSAMLAuthentication:511] - Profile Action ValidateSAMLAuthentication: No transcoding rule for Attribute (Name 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname', NameFormat: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified')
2023-01-30 23:12:10,735 - 10.254.252.105 - INFO [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.saml2.profile.impl.ValidateSAMLAuthentication:511] - Profile Action ValidateSAMLAuthentication: No transcoding rule for Attribute (Name 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname', NameFormat: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified')
2023-01-30 23:12:10,735 - 10.254.252.105 - INFO [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.saml2.profile.impl.ValidateSAMLAuthentication:511] - Profile Action ValidateSAMLAuthentication: No transcoding rule for Attribute (Name 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress', NameFormat: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified')
2023-01-30 23:12:10,735 - 10.254.252.105 - INFO [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.saml2.profile.impl.ValidateSAMLAuthentication:511] - Profile Action ValidateSAMLAuthentication: No transcoding rule for Attribute (Name 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name', NameFormat: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified')
2023-01-30 23:12:10,735 - 10.254.252.105 - DEBUG [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.saml2.profile.impl.ValidateSAMLAuthentication:482] - Profile Action ValidateSAMLAuthentication: Incoming SAML Attributes mapped to attribute IDs: []
2023-01-30 23:12:10,735 - 10.254.252.105 - INFO [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.saml2.profile.impl.ValidateSAMLAuthentication:326] - Profile Action ValidateSAMLAuthentication: SAML authentication succeeded for '<my_azure_email>'
2023-01-30 23:12:10,735 - 10.254.252.105 - DEBUG [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.saml2.profile.impl.ValidateSAMLAuthentication:361] - Profile Action ValidateSAMLAuthentication: Added translated AuthnContext Principals: [urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password]
2023-01-30 23:12:10,735 - 10.254.252.105 - DEBUG [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.saml2.profile.impl.ValidateSAMLAuthentication:300] - Profile Action ValidateSAMLAuthentication: Resetting authentication time to proxied value: 2023-01-31T00:58:45.582Z
2023-01-30 23:12:10,782 - 10.254.252.105 - DEBUG [net.shibboleth.idp.authn.impl.PopulateSubjectCanonicalizationContext:75] - Profile Action PopulateSubjectCanonicalizationContext: Installing 3 canonicalization flows into SubjectCanonicalizationContext
2023-01-30 23:12:10,782 - 10.254.252.105 - INFO [Shibboleth-Audit.SSO:338] - 2023-01-31T04:12:10.782744400Z|urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect|_2a73955fd5a49d06c9567eb52a05cd99|https://sts.windows.net/f42c8e55-f934-4f2c-b0ce-a1e403fd1b9d/|http://shibboleth.net/ns/profiles/saml2/sso/browser|https://<idp_url>/idp|urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST|_60d95c36-51de-45d7-bbcd-25539e822daf||urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password||<my_azure_email>|_75101b2a-a777-485e-ab76-c816ff9f4301|
2023-01-30 23:12:10,813 - 10.254.252.105 - DEBUG [net.shibboleth.idp.authn.impl.SelectSubjectCanonicalizationFlow:100] - Profile Action SelectSubjectCanonicalizationFlow: Checking canonicalization flow c14n/attribute for applicability...
2023-01-30 23:12:10,813 - 10.254.252.105 - DEBUG [net.shibboleth.idp.authn.impl.SelectSubjectCanonicalizationFlow:83] - Profile Action SelectSubjectCanonicalizationFlow: Selecting canonicalization flow c14n/attribute
2023-01-30 23:12:10,860 - 10.254.252.105 - DEBUG [net.shibboleth.idp.attribute.resolver.impl.AttributeResolverImpl:251] - Attribute Resolver 'ShibbolethAttributeResolver': Initiating attribute resolution with label: c14n/attribute
2023-01-30 23:12:10,860 - 10.254.252.105 - DEBUG [net.shibboleth.idp.attribute.resolver.impl.AttributeResolverImpl:469] - Attribute Resolver 'ShibbolethAttributeResolver': Resolving dependencies for 'passthroughAttributes'
2023-01-30 23:12:10,860 - 10.254.252.105 - DEBUG [net.shibboleth.idp.attribute.resolver.impl.AttributeResolverImpl:478] - Attribute Resolver 'ShibbolethAttributeResolver': Finished resolving dependencies for 'passthroughAttributes'
2023-01-30 23:12:10,860 - 10.254.252.105 - DEBUG [net.shibboleth.idp.attribute.resolver.impl.AttributeResolverImpl:424] - Attribute Resolver 'ShibbolethAttributeResolver': Resolving data connector passthroughAttributes
```

Eventually, this errors saying nothing can be mapped when building this out.  Anything anyone has seen in terms of mapping this out that could have been missed?  Have gone through all the mappings a number of times and not seeing where this could have been missed.

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the azureClaims.xml file in conf/attributes/default-rules.xml? (and restarted Tomcat/Jetty)

Its saying it can't find a transcoder for http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name (among others) - is this defined in azureClaims.xml? It should look something like:

```
        <bean parent="shibboleth.TranscodingProperties">
            <property name="properties">
                <props merge="true">
                    <prop key="id">azureName</prop>
                    <prop key="transcoder">SAML2ScopedStringTranscoder</prop>
                    <prop key="saml2.name">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name</prop>
                    <prop key="saml2.nameFormat">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified</prop>
                    <prop key="displayName.en">Name</prop>
                    <prop key="description.en">Azure UPN of an account expecting to be scoped thus transcoded that way</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

Specifically, the saml2.name needs to match than name of the attribute released by AzureAD - this should be shown in the assertion received from AzureAD a bit earlier in the process log.